# How to click on random element "N" number of times?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Requirement is to click on random element n times. (4 times)
Those elements have common CSS selector `[class*='SelectionContent']`.
My idea is to grab and store all element in array and then click on it using `Math.random function` I use this code for reference

`const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"]; const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * months.length); console.log(random, months[random]);`

but the problem is how I can click on element 4 times?

What I tried
`var items = Array(cy.get('[class*="style__SelectionContent"]')) Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length).click({ multiple: true });`

Comment: Put it in a loop that counts until the number of times is reached.

Comment: `click on element 4 times` - call `.click()` 4 times. Move random element generator to function and call it 4 times.

Comment: the problem here is if I pass `{ multiple: true }` then cypress try to click on all elements

Comment: `var items = cy.get()` does not work in Cypress, learn how to use chains.

Comment: @CherryDT you are right, i redid my tests and a simple for loop does the trick, it is obviously a single thread and each exec waits for the end of the previous one. I deleted my answer, it is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a simple [forLoop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   cy.get(element).click()
   cy.wait(100) //this is in case there is some rendering after click
}
```

Or with a [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/recursion)

```
function click4 (element, i = 0) {
   if (i>=4) { return }
   cy.get(element).click()
   cy.wait(100) //this is in case there is some rendering after click
   i++
   click4(element, i)
}
click4(element)
```